# Extract n words after a pattern word

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

This is my first time attempting to extract a string using gsub and regular expressions in R. I would like to extract three words after the first occurrence of the word "at" or "around" in each cell of a text column (col in example) and place the extraction into a new column (new_extract).

What I have thus far is the following:

```
df$new_extract <- gsub(".*at(\\w{1,}){3}).*", "\\1", df$col, perl = TRUE)
```

Any advice on changes / different approaches welcomed!

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex attempts to match words only after the *last* `at`. Also, since there is no pattern to match the gap between `at` or `around` (you are not trying to match `around` at all by the way), your pattern will not extract any words in the end.

I suggest this approach with `sub`:

```r
sub(".*?\\ba(?:t|round)\\W+(\\w+(?:\\W+\\w+){0,2}).*", "\\1", df$col, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4U48sP/2/).

Here,

- `.*?` - matches from the start,  any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\ba` - a word boundary and then `a`
- `(?:t|round)` - `t` or `round`
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `(\w+(?:\\W+\\w+){0,2})` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then zero, one or two occurrences of one or more non-word chars followed with one or more word chars
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: Hi @wiktor, thank you so much for your response! What would the above approach look like if it were only one pattern word (i.e. at)? I'm not very familiar with the regex syntax yet and had a difficult time reproducing this for one word (I know I originally said two pattern words in my example, but I tried to reproduce a more simplified version of the above and got stuck). Also, I only want to extract three words after the first occurrence of 'at', but when I used the line above it seems like it returned all the words after the pattern word (this may be user error!).

Comment: @LunaDeloge Replace `(?:t|round)` with `t`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4U48sP/3). Also, see [this R demo online](https://ideone.com/BjxsYH).